# The function $\dfrac 1 {e^x+x}$ has a vertical asymptote, but why?

Tags: calculus

The following function: $\dfrac 1 {e^x+x}$ has an horizontal asymptote (pretty normal to calculate) and a vertical one. But I can't see the magic behind the denominator $e^x + x$ so I don't understand how to set up the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the function $f(x):=e^x+x$ is continuous, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$, but also $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$.

In fact, we only need to know that there are two points $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1)>0>f(x_2)$. Now, since $f$ is continous, it must pass through $0$ at some point. Let this point be called $a$. We will have: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{1}{e^x+x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\pm\infty$ (the partial limits are either plus or negative infinity, or both of them. Nothing else)

Hence at that point $a$, there is a vertical asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the vertical asymptote would occur at some $x=a$ such that: $$e^a=-a$$
I do not think there is any elementary way to find this $a$, but you could plot it and find out.

Comment: ... and therefore, the solution to $e^a = -a$ is negative.

Comment: for negative $a$ its possible that $e^a=-a$, since $-a>0$...

Comment: Yeah, most definitely

Comment: Not only its not elementary to find such an $a$, if I remember correctly, there is no closed form to express such an $a$.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of a vertical asymptote it suffices to find $a$ such that $e^x+x \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a^+$ or $x \rightarrow a^-$. But since $e^x+x$ is continuous we simply need to find $a$ such that $e^a+a=0$. We can see such an $a$ exists in a number of ways, such as either graphically or by usage of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).